# Concatenate path and file

Tags: function, powershell, variables

I'm new to PowerShell, and am pretty happy with how far I've gotten with writing new functions etc, but this one has me stumped, such a simple thing ...

Below is the function:

```
Function fnConcatenatePathFile ([String]$Path, [String]$File)
{
   $FullPath = "$($Path)\$($File)"
   Return $FullPath
}
```

I then call the function like this:

```
fnConcatenatePathFile ("C:\_Store", "run.sql")
```

I expect the result to be:

```
"C:\_Store\run.sql"
```

But instead I get:

```
"C:\_Store run.sql\"
```

Driving me bonkers ... any clues?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel (yours incorrectly joins ```c:\``` and `file.txt`), use the built-in `Join-Path`.

Comment: `Join-Path` or `[system.IO.Path]::Combine("C:\_Store", "run.sql")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for calling functions. In Powershell you separate arguments by a space and you also don't need to use `()`.

`,` is the array-operator, so `"C:\_Store", "run.sql"` actually passes an array of two strings to `$Path` and because you're using the variable (containing an array) in a string, the strings are joined together with a whitespace. `$File` is empty, which is why it ends with nothing after `\`.

Try:

```
fnConcatenatePathFile "C:\_Store" "run.sql"
```

or to make it clearer:

```
fnConcatenatePathFile -Path "C:\_Store" -File "run.sql"
```

Comment: No problem. Updated with description to explain why it didn't work. Remember to mark as answer if it solved your problem so the question will get closed.

Answer (score 7):

Frode F. already [showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436139/1163423) what you did wrong. However, there is a [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to combine a path:

```
Join-Path "C:\_Store" "run.sql"
```

**Output:**

```
C:\_Store\run.sql
```